# SQL Server 2012 Can't create any table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I can't create any table in SQL Server. The error field always says, that there's something wrong near my table name.

Can somebody take a look at my syntax from the first table?

```
create table course
(c_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 r_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
 start date,    
 end date,
 name varchar(20),
 leader int,
 constraint pk_cousrse primary key (k_id, r_id, leader)

 );
insert into course (start, end, name, leader)
values (26.03.2012, 23.05.2013, , morrison);
```

Comment: Let's get past the fact that you want 2 identity columns on your table, your insert also doesn't make sense. For starters, you have a `leader` column that it's an `INT` and yet you want to insert `morrison` in it. You are also not taking into account that you need to use single quotes for strings (and that you also need to enclose your dates in single quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the wrong part is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. there is no `AUTO_INCREMENT` in SQL Server. It should be `IDENTITY`.

Again, you are trying to create two `IDENTITY` field in your table. that's not allowed. You can have only one `IDENTITY` field.

`start` and `end` are reserve word. You need to escape them using `[]` (square brackets)

You `CREATE` statement should look like

```
create table course (c_id int not null IDENTITY, r_id int not null , 
[start] date,
[end] date, 
name varchar(20), 
leader int, 
constraint pk_cousrse primary key (c_id, r_id, leader)
)
```

Comment: Hey,thank you very much, now i could create my 1st table! :)         Even though my insert into command still doesnt seem to work. Seems like theres something wrong with the dates:                                                            insert into course ([start], [end], name, leader) values (26.03.2012, 23.05.2013, 'c' , 'morrison');

Comment: @FelixBeer, you need to quote the date like `insert into course ([start], [end], name, leader) values ('26.03.2012', '23.05.2013', 'c' , 'morrison');`